# Mocha tests started failing for GET calls

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js

My mocha tests started failing after upgrading to Node 0.10 and Express 3. Every GET call fails with a 404 even though the PUT and POST calls on the same resources work correctly. The unit tests have not changed, and I've verified the endpoints using the browser. It's only within the context of Mocha that they fail with 404.

Here is an example test,

```
var user = new UserModel({
    email: 'mocha@example.com',
    pass: 'password',
    dob: Date.now(),
    role: 'patient'
});

var deviceid = null;
var notifications;

describe('Device Token API',function() {
    before(function(done) {
        mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/dev', function(err) {
            UserModel.remove({email:'mocha@example.com'},function(err){
                done(err);
            });
        });
    });
    describe('POST /api/users', function() {
        it('should allow creation of users', function(done) {
            request(app).post("/api/users")
            .send({password:'password',
                  confirm_password:'password',
                  email:'mocha@example.com',
                  fnam:'Mocha',
                  lnam:'Dude',
                  dob:new Date(1970,1,1)
            })
            .expect(201)
            .end(function(err,res) {
                user = res.body;
                done();
            });
        });
    });
    describe('POST /api/sign-in', function() {
        it('should allow user to sign-in', function(done) {
            request(app).post("/api/sign-in")
            .send( { email: 'mocha@example.com', password: 'password' })
            .expect(200)
            .end(function(err,res) {
                cookie = res.headers['set-cookie'];
                done();
            });
        });
    });
describe('POST /api/users/:userid/devicetokens', function() {
    it('should respond with 201 and id', function(done) {
        request(app).post("/api/users/" + user._id + "/devicetokens")
        .set('cookie',cookie)
        .send({
            token:'IOSTOKENFORPUSHNOTIFICATION',
            device: 'ios',
            device_name: 'mocha man phone'
        })
        .expect(201,function(err,res) {
            deviceid = res.body.id;
            done();
        });
    });
});
describe('PUT /api/users/:userid/devicetokens/:id', function() {
    it('should respond with 204', function(done) {
        request(app).put("/api/users/" + user._id + "/devicetokens/" + deviceid)
        .set('cookie',cookie)
        .send({
            token:'IOSTOKENFORPUSHNOTIFICATION2',
            device: 'ios',
            device_name: 'mocha man phone'
        })
        .expect(204,done);
    });

    it('should not allow mac address modification', function(done) {
        request(app).put("/api/users/" + user._id + "/devicetokens/" + deviceid)
        .set('cookie',cookie)
        .send({
            token:'IOSTOKENFORPUSHNOTIFICATION3',
            device: 'ios',
            device_name: 'mocha ipad'
        })
        .expect(500,done);
    });
});
    describe('GET /api/users/:userid/devicetokens', function() {
        it('should respond with a single device token', function(done) {
            request(app).get("/api/users/" + user._id + "/devicetokens/")
            .set('cookie',cookie)
            .expect(200)
            .end(function(err,res) {
                console.dir(res.body);
                res.body.should.have.length(1);
                res.body[0].token.should.equal('IOSTOKENFORPUSHNOTIFICATION2');
                res.body[0].device.should.equal('ios');
                res.body[0].device_name.should.equal('mocha man phone');
                done();
            });
        });
    });
});
```

None of the middleware I use fires from Mocha so the 404 has to be buried inside of Express somewhere. Not shown in this example are the PUT and POST calls, which work correctly so I'm confident the route definitions are working.

Here are the Mocha results,

```
HOST=local TZ=UTC REDIS_ENV=on ./node_modules/.bin/mocha --bail --ignore-leaks --reporter spec --timeout 10s test/devicetokens.api.js
INFO - Fri, 29 Nov 2013 20:35:03 GMT - Host name is localhost:8080
INFO - Fri, 29 Nov 2013 20:35:03 GMT - server started on port 8080


  Device Token API
    POST /api/users
      ◦ should allow creation of users: INFO - Fri, 29 Nov 2013 20:35:03 GMT - ... sign-up in group undefined
INFO - Fri, 29 Nov 2013 20:35:03 GMT - New user creation:
INFO - Fri, 29 Nov 2013 20:35:03 GMT - ... email sent
INFO - Fri, 29 Nov 2013 20:35:03 GMT -  to: mocha@example.com
      ✓ should allow creation of users (130ms)
INFO - Fri, 29 Nov 2013 20:35:03 GMT - 127.0.0.1 - POST /api/users 201 557 - 125 ms
    POST /api/sign-in
      ✓ should allow user to sign-in 
INFO - Fri, 29 Nov 2013 20:35:03 GMT - 127.0.0.1 - POST /api/sign-in 200 557 - 11 ms
    POST /api/users/:userid/devicetokens
      ◦ should respond with 201 and id: DEBUG - Fri, 29 Nov 2013 20:35:03 GMT - {
    token: 'IOSTOKENFORPUSHNOTIFICATION',
    device: 'ios',
    device_name: 'mocha man phone'
}
      ✓ should respond with 201 and id 
INFO - Fri, 29 Nov 2013 20:35:03 GMT - 127.0.0.1 - POST /api/users/5298fa7741fb79cbbf000019/devicetokens 201 38 - 22 ms
    PUT /api/users/:userid/devicetokens/:id
      ◦ should respond with 204: INFO - Fri, 29 Nov 2013 20:35:03 GMT - 127.0.0.1 - PUT /api/users/5298fa7741fb79cbbf000019/devicetokens/5298fa7741fb79cbbf000031 204 - - 7 ms
      ✓ should respond with 204 
      ✓ should not allow mac address modification 
INFO - Fri, 29 Nov 2013 20:35:03 GMT - 127.0.0.1 - PUT /api/users/5298fa7741fb79cbbf000019/devicetokens/5298fa7741fb79cbbf000031 500 4 - 8 ms
    GET /api/users/:userid/devicetokens
      ◦ should respond with a single device token: INFO - Fri, 29 Nov 2013 20:35:03 GMT - 127.0.0.1 - GET /api/users/5298fa7741fb79cbbf000019/devicetokens/ 404 - - 3 ms
{}
ERROR - Fri, 29 Nov 2013 20:35:03 GMT - Caught Error AssertionError: expected {} to have a property 'length'
```

Comment: I did. I've been able to verify it both with a database lookup as well as using the API directly in the browser. Finally, as I noted, PUT and POST calls work without error.

Comment: @Greg are you using [`strict routing`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app-settings) in Express? Your description of the `GET` test mentions a URL without a trailing `/` while your actual request uses one.

Comment: I am not using strict. I just verified both paths (slash, no-slash) work via the browser.

Comment: I should rephrase - I am not explicitly setting strict routing.